# When does a cached Big Query job expire?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am currently using bigquery and whenever a query is run, the job is cached in memory and subsequent pages can be fetched from the cached table. So, is there a fixed expiration date for the cached tables? What factors does the job data persistence depend on? I am trying to see if the job still exists if I come back after a week or a month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly from [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#querycaching) (if you Google "App Engine BigQuery Caching") :

Results are cached for approximately 24 hours and cache lifetimes are extended when a query returns a cached result.

So basically, as long as you get your cached result once every 24 hours, cache should stay indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking on the bigquery jobs page and couldn't find anything re the caching.